# How to apply background Gradient style css

Tags: css, background, styles, gradient, opacity

I want to apply nackground gradient style like this -> http://nimb.ws/Xq79Uw

Following is HTML code:

```
<div class="featured-title zl-artful-featured-title">
   <aside class="post-meta cf">
      <a aria-label="Artful Interiors" class="cat-artful-interiors" href="http://localhost/magnifissance/?cat=86">Artful Interiors</a>                                          
   </aside>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="columns medium-10">
         <div class="post-title zl-artful-interi-title">
            <a href="http://localhost/magnifissance/?p=12466">Enrico Fratesi Shares His Vision of Form, Tradition and Renewal</a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="columns medium-2">
         <figure class="post-gallery "></figure>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Any one have a idea for this type style then please update me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the gradient is on top of the image in your example. This code using pseudo elements will do that for you, vs putting the gradient code on the div itself.

```
#artful_interiors .post > a {
    position: relative;
}

#artful_interiors .post > a:before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient( to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, #000 95% );
}
```

Comment: I added above css but it looks like this -> http://nimb.ws/CwMDrR not display content in full width. Display spaces in left and right side.

Comment: That means you're on the wrong element. Move the CSS from `.zl-artful-featured-title` to one of it's parent containers. Without having your code it's hard to tell, but I'd wager it would be `.zl-artful` or `.zl-artful-featured`

Comment: I have already applied style in parent class `.zl-artful-featured-title` but that display out put like this ->  http://nimb.ws/CwMDrR

Comment: I understand that, you want it to cover the whole image, correct? The `.zl-artful-featured-title` is the wrong element. You need to move the pseudo element CSS from that to the parent element that contains the image.

Comment: No not whole image. I only wan to cover that section bottom part text section.

Comment: Can you post a link to your site? There's clearly a bit of a communication issue and it's terribly hard to help with screenshots.

Comment: I've updated the code in my answer, here's an example: https://i.imgur.com/D0Bxktg.png

Comment: That's work good and How can i apply that same style in Home page first section post big banner image -> http://nimb.ws/rwOhxb  ?

Comment: I have managed that with my self for Home page big featured image. 

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out - I was just about to post it. My pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

```css
#zl-artful-featured-title{
   background: linear-gradient(
    to top,
    #63B4C9  35%,
    #FFFFFF 70%
  );
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:260px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="zl-artful-featured-title">
    <p>Content</p>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTvbOaFeLuR9IUkcut98bJs4r7-Qm8AGcEEYiiKxiAZEiljvUS_"/>
</div>
```

Try this

```
#zl-artful-featured-title{
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #63B4C9 35%, #FFFFFF 40%);

}
```

If not working try this

```
 #zl-artful-featured-title{
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    #63B4C9  35%,
    #FFFFFF 70%
  );
}
```

Make sure you've change the # to . if your using class.
I hope it helps

Comment: what's your browser? may I see the result?

Comment: Issues in your style. Style not display in inspect element. So please review your style and update me.

Comment: did you change # to . ? because you're using class not id like my sample above

Comment: Yes i do that but style not appear.

Comment: try my new snippet